# Terminal history is being deleted upon ending session

Tags: bash, debian, command-history

My `~/.bash_history` is fine and has all of the previous commands that I ever typed. However, when I press the up-arrow key on the keyboard, I get nothing; the `history` command shows only the commands that I typed in this session only. How can I fix that?

I use Debian Stretch and GNOME Terminal.

**Updates:**

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

.

```
$ cat .bash_logout 
# ~/.bash_logout: executed by bash(1) when login shell exits.

# when leaving the console clear the screen to increase privacy

if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> only shows the commands I typed in this session

for example, if I opened a new terminal window there will be no history at all, if I typed a command then the history is this command only

**Update 2.0**

`su` 's history is working normally with no problems, it's just my user

I even created a new user and tested its history and it's working great

```
rahman@www:~$ history 
    1  history 
rahman@www:~$ su
Password: 
root@www:/home/rahman# history 10
  314  aptitude show linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64
  315  aptitude show linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
  316  aptitude install firmware-linux-free irqbalance
  317  aptitude safe-upgrade
  318  aptitude safe-upgrade -y
  319  exit
  320  exit
  321  exit
  322  history 4
  323  history 10
root@www:/home/rahman# exit
exit
rahman@www:~$ history 10
    1  history 
    2  su
    3  history 10
```

**Update 3.0**

```
rahman@www:~$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/rahman/.bash_history
rahman@www:~$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
```

will someone help me, please? this problem is very annoying and pisses me off.

Comment: Check that there are no entries relating to history in /home/<username>/.bash_logout

Comment: There are two problems. If you press Control-R, could you look on history? What value do you have on HISTFILE, HISTSIZE. What permission on your .bash_history. Note: if you have two open shell, sometime one will overwrite the other history.

Comment: I've updated the question with the info you needed

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud You never mentioned `HISTFILE`.

Comment: In addition to the output of `echo $HISTFILE`, please add the output of `echo $HISTCONTROL`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've added `$HISTFILE` which is `~/.bash_history`

Comment: @TimothyMartin `$HISTCONTROL` is `ignoreboth`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this [link](https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/ubuntu-enable-bash-history/)

and the problem got resolved by running

```
sudo chown <user> .bash_history
```